# Jpa Hibernate não cria tabela no H2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, h2database, spring-tools-suite

Boa noite,

Sou novo em desenvolvimento Java - Spring Boot e seguindo um tutorial não consigo gerar a tabela no banco de dados H2, ja tentei fazer algumas alterações na application.propreties mas sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.0.0.RELEASE
         
    
    com.julio.cursomc
    cursomc
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    cursomc
    Estudo de casa Java para curso de modelagem conceitual com UML

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está utilizando properties erradas, deve ser:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Como descrito nas docs:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".
```

Você pode conferir as properties corretas na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

---

Sua estrutura de pacotes está incorreta, por gentileza siga a estrutura descrita na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html).

Em resumo:

- Component Scan é a funcionalidade do Spring que escaneia suas classes e configura automaticamente entidades e classes de serviço, repositórios, etc...

Isso é automaticamente realizado para todos os pacotes que se encontram abaixo da hierarquia da sua classe `main`, no seu caso `com.example.demo`.

Você possui classes fora dessa hierarquia (como a `curso.julio.cursomc.domain`. Essas classes não serão escaneadas.

Altere a hierarquia de seus pacotes e deve funcionar de acordo.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, porem mesmo após a correção a tabela não foi criada no banco.

Comment: Seria possível disponibilizar a estrutura do seu projeto? Suas entidades estão na hierarquia de component scan do spring boot?

Comment: Neste momento do tutorial em que estou seguindo, ainda não foi explanado nada sobre component Scan, no momento em que o instrutor cria as tabelas no banco, só existem 3 classes. Os códigos estão em anexo.

Comment: @JULIOCESARSILVADEFREITAS editei a resposta com informações novas

Answer (score -3):

Tive problemas pois o H2 não gerava as tabelas via Java Spring Boot. Depois de muitos dias procurando a causa descobri que o problema simplesmente estava no arquivo pom.xml. Havia duas linhas de código do pom.xml que, por algum motivo estavam juntas na mesma linha. Isso fazia com que o H2 não gerasse as tabelas criadas. É preciso que o arquivo pom.xml esteja todo certo, sem esse tipo de problema. Simples de corrigir mas complicado de descobrir!